# How to tame Nautilus sidebar to show local volumes and removable media?

Tags: fstab, nautilus

Nautilus used to show my local volumes and removable media properly, but that does not work on a new computer I just installed (clean system). See the example below with Nautilus v. 3.26.4 on the left and Caja v. 1.22.1 on the right:

[image]

As you can see from `/etc/fstab` below, all drives have the `x-gvfs-show` tag:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <fs>      <mountpoint> <type> <opts>      <dump/pass>

# /dev/ROOT   /            ext3    noatime        0 1
# /dev/SWAP   none         swap    sw             0 0
# /dev/fd0    /mnt/floppy  auto    noauto         0 0
none        /proc        proc    nosuid,noexec  0 0
none        /dev/shm     tmpfs   defaults       0 0
UUID=0c5d7c4b-796e-4765-a7e9-91e9517dcb1a   swap    swap    sw  0   0

# /dev/SolusSystem/Root at time of installation
UUID=e6ffae94-4472-454d-be5f-80d7d429def7   /   ext4    rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro   0   1


# Extra drives
/dev/sdb1 /run/media/mathieu/SSD1TB ext4 defaults,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=SSD1TB 0 2
/dev/sdf1 /run/media/mathieu/DATA auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=DATA 0 0
/dev/sda2 /run/media/mathieu/INT4TB auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=INT4TB 0 0
/dev/sde1 /run/media/mathieu/PHOTO auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=PHOTO,noauto 0 0
/dev/sdd1 /run/media/mathieu/PHOTO-BACKUP auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-name=PHOTO-BACKUP,noauto,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

While Caja manages to interpret `/etc/fstab` properly, Nautilus mixes things up and hides local volumes. Plus, for some reason, it considers `/dev/sdf1` as a removable media, which it is not, and I don't know what may cause that.

SSD1TB is ext4; DATA, INT4TB, PHOTO and PHOTO-BACKUP are NTFS (for now).

I do not want to use Caja so I would be very grateful if someone could help me fixing Nautilus sidebar.

Comment: using x-gvfs-show works for me with nautilus 3.36.1.1 in xubuntu 20.04